# stl codecvt errors c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, stl, codecvt

i want to use the codecvt to convert the std:wstring to std::string like so

```
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <codecvt>

//some additional code

typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_typeX;
std::wstring_convert<wchar_t> converterX;
```

I'am using vs2012, and i get the following compilation errors:

```
error C2825: '_Codecvt': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
error C2039: 'state_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

All this errors generates from the file xlocbuf on the line

```
typedef typename _Codecvt::state_type state_type;
```

_Codevct is defined there as template, what can be wrong with it? Please help!

Comment: What term is wrong? You can edit your question and correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first template parameter of `std::wstring_convert` should be a `codecvt` class. `wchar_t` is not such a class. You likely want

```
std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX> converterX;
```

If not, what have you declared `convert_typeX` for?

Comment: Thanks, it was error on my side, i messed up the example code a little bit.